# GET parameter to the list in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, get

I have to submit name from the form and receive the value in GET method.
Received value in URL should be shown up on top of form as a list.
I want to **show all input from form submit** as unordered list.
But my code only shows the latest input.

Friend class has
private String friend and getter setters.

```
@Controller
public class FriendController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/index")
    public String friendForm(@RequestParam(value = "friend", required = false) Friend friend, Model model) {
        
        List<Friend> fList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
        fList.add(friend);      
        model.addAttribute("friends", fList);
        model.addAttribute("friend", new Friend());
        
        
            return "result";
        

    }

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Friends List</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    

        <h1 th:text="'My Friends'"></h1>
        <ul>
            <li th:each="friend: ${friends}" th:text="${friend}"></li>
        </ul>


    <h1 th:text="'Add a new friend to List'"></h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/index}" th:object="${friend}"
        method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{friend}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `Friend` class have a field named `friend`? --- *"show all input from form submit"* But there is only one input, so what "all" are you expecting?

Comment: are you expecting a list of friends ? Because you are only sending one friend at a time

Comment: Yes.
- Friend class has only private String friend; as a member and getters setters. 
- I expect a list of friends